# How do I get response from ActiveResource's `update_attribute` method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an API and I am using ActiveResouce to interact with it. 
One of the end point of the API is `update`.

I am doing user validation errors server side, and returning error response back to the client in case of user validation errors.

But `.update_attributes` returns boolean value, `true`/`false`. I want to use the error response so that I can render it in the UI. How can I do that?

Comment: With an `if` statement??

Comment: initially `.update_attributes` will skip the validation, use `.update` https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute

Comment: @Shiko You are wrong. [update_attributes](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attributes) is an alias for [update](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update) as docs say

Comment: @MartinZinovsky you have reason, I have wrongly mixed between `update_attributes` and `update_attribute`.

Answer (score 2):

`update_attributes` just returns a boolean set to `true` when the save was made correctly.

If you want to check for errors, you can call `model.errors` and see the messages.

```
user = User.first
user.update_attributes(username: '') #=> false
user.errors.to_a #=> ["Username can't be blank", "Username must be at least 3 characters"]
```

You can format and return these errors in your API as you want

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation in the source code](https://github.com/rails/activeresource/blob/b71ded7e1b9004c7a24f28203c35c7ad24da6617/lib/active_resource/base.rb#L1476) indicates that an error will raise an exception. You could rescue that exception and return something depending from whatever method you're calling it from. This is just an basic example, but you would want to catch the exception raised, not `StandardError`, but probably `ActiveResource`.  Since I'm not sure what exception exactly, you can try this and see what the actual exception is, and use that to return something useful in the method.

```
def some_method(params)
  some_api_obj.update_attributes(params)
  rescue Exception => e
  puts e
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To assure your records are **validated**, proceed using `.update` or `.update_attributes` as you are doing but you need to set the record first to a variable to get the details of the error if there is.

```
user = User.first
user.update(name: "Voldemore")
pp user.errors # return array of errors where you can send to UI
```

Reference for update methods with callbacks and validation:
http://www.davidverhasselt.com/set-attributes-in-activerecord/

Comment: the question is regarding `ActiveResource` not `ActiveRecord` however you're answer may still be correct.